# jQuery - drag element inside DIV / or sortable element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm having a problem with dragging a div inside an other div element.

HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="grid">
    <div id="el1" style="width:300px"></div>
    <div id="el2" style="width:100px"></div>
    <div id="el3" style="width:100px"></div>
    <div id="el4" style="width:100px"></div>
</div>
```

All elements are draggable and have the css style `float:left;position:relative;`.
When I drag `el1` to the place of `el3` it will work, but of course it will overlap the element `el3`.
The draggin `jquery draggable` is working fine but I want to insert div with id `el1`at the HTML code in this position.

That it will look like this:

```
<div id...>
    <div id="el2...
    <div id="el3...
    <div id="el1...
    <div id="el4...
</div>
```

My problem now is, that this is a grid. `el1` has the width of '300' all other the width of '100'. Dragin `el1` to the place of `el3` should swap `el2`, `el3` and `el4` to the place of `el1` and `el1` to the place of `el2, el3, el4`.

To get this behaviour I think I'm needed to move the `div` HTML code after `el4`. But how to determine which element is the nearest?

**------- UPDATED-------**

**I way trying to use sortable... see here http://jsfiddle.net/vwK5e/2/
But if you put the red box over number 3, the red box will be in the second line (correct) but number 4 should be next to number 3 cause of the empty space.**

TIA
frgtv10

Comment: What exactly is your problem. I didn't have read anything in your question, that isn't covered through [jQuery UI Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/).

Comment: I know that its not covered. Thats why I asked for a solution :) I updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#display-grid

I guess you want functionality like this.

Answer

[A different kind of jquery sortable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500302/a-different-kind-of-jquery-sortable)

Comment: I already tried this, but if you have different sizes of elements it will not work. Although with sortable, I have the problem with empty space. If I would move it like described above, the empty space is not used. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: please have a look at here and the comment above in my question (updated)--> http://jsfiddle.net/vwK5e/2/

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5500302/a-different-kind-of-jquery-sortable

Answer (score 0):

My solution looks like this:

Instead of jQuerys `draggable` I'm now using `sortable` (link to [sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/)).
In addition to this I'm now getting the help of the jQuery plugin called `masonry`(link to [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/index.html))

Example:

```
// Masonry
$('#container').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.element',
    isResizable: true,
    columnWidth: 100
})


// Sortable 
$('#container').sortable({
    items: '.element',
    forcePlaceholderSize: true,
    placeholder: 'card-sortable-placeholder element',
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    handle: '.handle',
    cursor: 'move',
    cancel: '.notdrag',

    start:  function(event, ui) {     
            ui.item.addClass('dragging').removeClass('element');
            ui.item.parent().masonry('reload')
        },
    change: function(event, ui) {
               ui.item.parent().masonry('reload');
        },
    stop:   function(event, ui) { 
               ui.item.removeClass('dragging').addClass('element');
               ui.item.parent().masonry('reload');
        }

    });
```